# What should be the volume level of monitors during mixing?

Tags: mixing, levels

Should the volume be kept low or a bit on the higher side during mixing?I am just a beginner so....

Answer (score 2):

Low or somewhere inbetween. Unless you have acoustic treatment like baffles and obsorbers, defusers. If you have the level too high you will 'excite' the room causing potentially standing waves; peaks and troughs that are stationary. If you are sat in either a node or anti node (technical term for aforementioned) you'll end up with a thin sounding mix or bass heavy sounding mix. Theres other things to consider but I've given you the basics of what happens if having your speakers too loud.

Comment: Low is not a good recommendation also as the bass will noy be present